# PCL_tutorial, how to show the point cloud

Tags: kinect, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am following the tutorial of PCL with ROS ([www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials)).

When i launch the openni i can see the topic is publishing. But when i try to use it to see the result, nothing happen (only black screen is showed in the rviz window).

What i have to do to show the result?

here is the code i use:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
// PCL specific includes
#include <pcl/ros/conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>

ros::Publisher pub;

void cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud){
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_filtered;

 // Perform the actual filtering
pcl::VoxelGrid<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> sor;
sor.setInputCloud (cloud);
sor.setLeafSize (0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
sor.filter (cloud_filtered);

// Publish the data
pub.publish (cloud_filtered);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv){
// Initialize ROS
ros::init (argc, argv, "my_pcl_tutorial");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

 // Create a ROS subscriber for the input point cloud
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("input", 1, cloud_cb);

// Create a ROS publisher for the output point cloud
pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("output", 1);

// Spin
ros::spin ();
}
```

Thanks

--Pierre

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48583/pcl_tutorial,-how-to-show-the-point-cloud/) by [Pierre](https://answers.ros.org/users/3625/pierre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-11-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-11-19**:
Did you add the correct type and the topic you're interested in correctly in Rviz?

**Comment by [Pierre](https://answers.ros.org/users/3625/pierre/) on 2012-11-19**:
I think so. I add a pointCloud2. And in the topic i selected the output(sensor_msgs/PointCloud2).

**Comment by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on 2012-11-19**:
What about the topic you subscribe to? If you try to catch the data published by openni node, the topic you subscribe to shouldn't be "input".

**Comment by [Pierre](https://answers.ros.org/users/3625/pierre/) on 2012-11-19**:
For the topic i subscribe i just followed the tutorial putting in the terminal:  rosrun my_pcl_tutorial example input:=/narrow_stereo_textured/points2

**Comment by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on 2012-11-19**:
If you're using openni (assuming you're using the openni_launch files), your input cloud should be /camera/depth/points or /camera/depth_registered/points. Nothing in openni_launch publishes /narrow_stereo_textured/point2. The PCL tutorial assumes you have a stereo vision system that does.

**Comment by [Pierre](https://answers.ros.org/users/3625/pierre/) on 2012-11-20**:
I don't understand, because yesterday i tried it with input:=/camera/depth_registered/points and that produced an error on the openni_launch terminal. But today it works... Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please check this page( http://answers.ros.org/question/153936/how-to-execute-a-example-in-pcl-tutorial/?comment=154396#comment-154396 ) if you have some trouble. I think that a result on this page is useful for you.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0